# Reading Charles Stross Laundry Series out of order

Tags: suggested-order, charles-stross, laundry-files

I have just bought the The Fuller Memorandum and realized that it is the 3rd book in a series.

Is it OK to read just this one, or should I read the other 2 first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the series share the same protagonist (Bob Howard), they're 3 different books, even different writing styles and can all be read apart.

> Where *The Atrocity Archives* was written in the idiom of Len Deighton and *The Jennifer Morgue* was a pastiche of Ian Fleming's James Bond novels, *The Fuller Memorandum* is a homage of sorts to Anthony Price's *Dr David Audley/Colonel Jack Butler* series of spy thrillers, and features two minor characters named Roskill and Panin, names which appeared as recurring characters in Price's series.
>
> <sub>[*Wikipedia*, "The Laundry Files: *The Fuller Memorandum*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laundry_Files#The_Fuller_Memorandum)</sub>

Comment: I agree, they _can_ be read apart. But I think they work a lot better in sequence.

Comment: I think this answer has dated badly as the series has continued. I think it was a reasonable opinion for the first few but the newer books really do have to be read in order and, as other answers have pointed out, some even overlap chronologically.

Answer (score 10):

Read them [in order](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2016/04/faq-the-laundry-filesseries-ti.html) for maximum enjoyment and understanding:

1. *The Atrocity Archives*
2. *The Jennifer Morgue*
3. "Down on the Farm"
4. "Equoid"
5. *The Fuller Memorandum*
6. "Overtime"
7. *The Apocalypse Codex*
8. *The Rhesus Chart*
9. *The Annihilation Score*
10. *The Nightmare Stacks*
11. *The Delirium Brief*
12. "The Howard/O'Brien Relate Counseling Session Transcripts – Part 1"

Also read [Mr Stross' blog](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/index.html) for further fascinating information

Comment: Agreed.  I started reading with "Down on the Farm" and must say I would have been better placed to enjoy it fully if I had read the earlier books first.

Answer (score 8):

I'm just reading the forth book "The Apocalypse Codex" and I also recognize that Stross always gives short introductions into relevant aspects of the story. So, you'd still understand most of what happens without reading the other books.

But I strongly advise you to read them in order. Especially "The Apocalypse Codex" has many references to previous topics, e.g., "destiny entanglement" and such. Personally, I wouldn't have had that much fun reading it if I had read it out of order.

Answer (score 6):

According to the author, [the chronological order of all current and projected books is as follows](https://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2020/10/the-laundry-files-an-updated-c.html).

- *The Atrocity Archives*
  which collects

  - *The Atrocity Archive*
  - *The Concrete Jungle*
- *The Jennifer Morgue*
  which includes

  - *Pimpf*
- *Down on the Farm* ([available online](https://www.tor.com/2008/07/20/down-on-the-farm/))
- *Equoid* ([available online](https://www.tor.com/2013/09/24/equoid/))
- *The Fuller Memorandum*
- *Overtime* ([available online](https://www.tor.com/2009/12/22/overtime/))
- *The Apocalypse Codex*
- *A Conventional Boy* (not yet written)
- *The Rhesus Chart*
- *The Annihilation Score*
- *Escape from Yokailand*
- *The Nightmare Stacks*
- *The Delirium Brief*
- *The Labyrinth Index*
- *The Valkyrie Confessional* (working title, not yet written)
- *Dead Lies Dreaming*
- *Quantum of Nightmares*
- *Season of Skulls* (not yet published)

The last three of these are set after the events of the main *Laundry Files* storyline.

According to the same FAQ, there are several possible starting points. Mr. Stross considers *The Rhesus Chart* a good starting point if you want to skip the early books. And since *Dead Lies Dreaming* is set after the conclusion of the main story line, he considers that a good starting point as well.

> **TLDR version**: If you just want to know where to start reading, pick one of: **The Atrocity Archives**, **The Rhesus Chart**, **The Nightmare Stacks**, or **Dead Lies Dreaming**. These are all safe starting points for the series, that don't require prior familiarity. Other books might leave you confused if you dive straight in [...]

---

Now to answer your question, the protagonist is always thoroughly introduced in the first chapter, as well as his unusual occupation. I'd say *The Fuller Memorandum* is as good a starting point as any, since I consider it a requisite for *The Rhesus Chart*.

Comment: I read them as they came out (except for the short stories, which I read later), and I think that is the best order. Reading the _Fuller Memorandum_ first I feel is a bad choice because it depends on a lot of other information given in the earlier books. I'm not even fond of _Rhesus Chart_ as a starting point, because the first chapter of that book is the same as the final chapter of the previous book, from a different point of view. Each book builds on the previous books.